# Strict data validation with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am working with MySQL Workbench and I noticed that my table was accepting pretty much any values without doing any data validation. Setting the **sql_mode to "STRICT_ALL_TABLES"** solved most of my problems.

However, when I insert a floating point value in a integer column, the value is rounded to the nearest int.

My question is: is there a way to force MySQL Workbench to throw an error instead of doing a rounding operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a design dilemma between being friendly and doing what you mean, or being a pain-in-the-a@@ and making you work harder.

If such validation is valuable, add a frontend interface which performs those sorts of validations, including cross-field and cross-table validation.  While you're at it, helpfully suggest field values from correlation with historical values, etc.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that. The thing is, the application I'm developping will be called many hundred times a second, so doing this kind of "heavy" validation is not really an option. So there is no native way of doing that kind of validation with MySQL Workbench?